# Can I make smoke to cast light?

Tags: light, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Is there any way to cause (or fake) light emission from the fire within a smoke simulation? Obviously smoke doesn't work in Cycles but is it possible in **BI** for the flames to contribute light to the scene in the same way that **FumeFX** does in **3ds Max**?

Alternatively is it possible to convert a flame into a cloud of particles in order to hack this somehow on a different pass?

Comment: You could add a point lamp to simulate some of it, but it won't cast sharp light (if that was what you wanted).

Comment: Maybe something with lamp textures?

Comment: Cycles will have Volume rendering soon (currently experimental in GSOC-2013-Dingto), so you might be able to do an emissive volume with that.

Comment: Smoke can now be rendered in Cycles, new in blender 2.70

Comment: @Vader Smoke can't be rendered in 2.70, but it can in later development versions (as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB691c4c17ad2f4b4e043f0961211ac90ca1656a8f))

Comment: @gandalf3 what is the ETA until smoke can be rendered?

Answer (score 3):

What I do is in the Blender Internal Renderer select the material that is going to have light cast on it. Then enable mirroring and turn down the glossiness.
[image]

You can adjust the number of samples it uses for smoother results.

[image: material settings floor]

Sorry for the wait, lack of internet at my home right now.

Comment: Can you add a photo of your material setup?

Comment: @CharlesL here you go, sorry for the wait

Answer (score -4):

I think that if you go to your texture influence properties for your domain object (voxel data), and check 'emission' it should work.[image: emmision]

Comment: This will make the smoke/fire brighter, but it won't actually illuminate other objects.